# Radix sort for non-negative integers (bitwise)

Tags: c, bit-shift, radix-sort, bitwise-and

I am trying to learn how to work with bitwise shifts and sorting algorithms, and I am lost. I want to use the binary representation of integers and using bitwise operations to sort the integers using radix sort. I already applied a radix sort using decimal in C (code below), but I am not sure how to do apply the same logic to a radix sort using bitwise operations. I think I would use the mask of 0xFF to left shift the binary representation of the integers.

How would I go about applying a radix sort to integer values using a left shift and a bitwise AND?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int arr[], int size){
    int max = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1;i<size;i++){
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
void radixsort(int arr[], int size) {
    int maxNum = max(arr, size);
    int tenExp;
    for (tenExp = 1; maxNum / tenExp > 0; tenExp *= 10){
        int returnArr[size];
        int i, numOccurences[10] = { 0 };
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            numOccurences[(arr[i] / tenExp) % 10]++;
        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            numOccurences[i] += numOccurences[i - 1];
        for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            returnArr[numOccurences[(arr[i] / tenExp) % 10] - 1] = arr[i];
            numOccurences[(arr[i] / tenExp) % 10]--;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            arr[i] = returnArr[i];
    }
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int size = 0;
    int* array = malloc(0 * sizeof(int));
    int res;
    int temp;
    int count;
    int i = 1;

    printf("Enter a count: ");
    scanf("%d",&count);


    while(i <= count){
        printf("Enter number: \n");
        res = scanf("%d",&temp);
        if(res == EOF) break;
        size++;
        array = realloc(array,size*sizeof(int));
        array[size-1] = temp;
        i++;
    }
    radixsort(array,size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's non-negative why don't use an `unsigned` type?

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to modify the same code to do a radix-sort for binary numbers only using arithmetic operations. This should be simple. You have to perform operation using `2` instead of `10`.

Once you do the above changes, you can use following equivalent bitwise operation.

`y = x>>1` is equivalent to `y = x/2`

`y = x<<1` is equivalent to `y = x*2`

`y = x&1` is equivalent to `y = x%2`

Comment: I changed *= 10 and % 10 to *= 10 and % 2. And then, I changed those to exp<<1 and numOccurences[(arr[i] / exp)&1]++. But these bitwise operations do not seem to work. Would you be able to provide further clarification?

Comment: At first, just change the 10 to 2 in the function `radixsort`. Check whether that works for you or not. After that change the operators to bitwise operators. If it still does not work for you, paste the new code here again.

Comment: void radixsort(int arr[], int size) {
    int maxNum = max(arr, size);
    int tenExp;
    for (tenExp = 1; maxNum / tenExp > 0; tenExp<<1){
     int returnArr[size];
     int i, numOccurences[10] = { 0 };
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
         numOccurences[(arr[i] / tenExp)&1]++;
     for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
         numOccurences[i] += numOccurences[i - 1];
     for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         returnArr[numOccurences[(arr[i] / tenExp)&1] - 1] = arr[i];
         numOccurences[(arr[i] / tenExp)&1]--;
     }
 }
}

Comment: change
`for (tenExp = 1; maxNum / tenExp > 0; tenExp<<1)` to `for (tenExp = 1; maxNum / tenExp > 0; tenExp = tenExp<<1)`